# Who and how writes L2 transaction to L1?

Tags: sidechain, layer-2

I read the document of Optimistic, I understood the L2 nodes send the transaction together to L1. However, I couldn't understand how L2 nodes pay the transaction fee.

https://community.optimism.io/docs/developers/fees.html#fees-for-l2-transactions

Is the L2 nodes pay tx fee on behalf of us? Or is it paid form the transaction fee in L2?